# Access Left Outer Join Query Extremely Slow

Tags: ms-access

I have seen this question asked many times before, but they all involved a query created with code.

I am doing the basic create query procedure where I manually drag field names from one table to another to join them. I am joining a query's output with a table. The first query outputs a table with around 3 fields and 30 records (This first query doesn't take more than 3 sec). The second table is around 15 fields and 30,000 records. I join the query with the table using 3 fields and I display all query records whether joint or not (thus the left outer join).

However, this procedure takes at least 2 mins to complete...

I cannot add a primary key to either as one is a query and the other is a linked data table that I cannot change.

Any suggestions as to how I could make this faster or have another idea to go about this????

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the data types of the fields and the SQL statement that is rendered (which you can get in SQL view instead of Design view). Edit your post with this information and not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said anything about indexes, so this answer assumes you haven't used any. You can significantly speed up queries by creating secondary indexes on joined fields (the "primary index" is on the primary key field).

For more information on how to do this, see [this post](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce) from Microsoft Office support. It should give you all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I couldnt add any indexes to the linked table as the design cannot be changed.

Comment: @ExamFML You didn't mention that your big table was a linked table from another  DB that you couldn't modify. But have a look at [this](https://digitalenginesoftware.com/blog/archives/61-Indexes-on-Linked-TablesViews-in-Access.html) before you give up on the idea. Look at the "pseudo-index" option that it explains. I've never done this before, but it appears to allow you to create an index on your end when you create the table link.

Comment: Thanks @BobRodes, I will try that out :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem in the future, I ended up changing my queries to make table queries and it was much faster. I also noticed pass through queries to be even faster but I wanted to avoid choosing my odbc table everytime I run it so I stuck with make table queries.